# Glyphicon NOT placed inside textbox & glyphicon calender size issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate two form fields, named "start date" & money. Both fields have a simple validation method where the **required** is set to **true**. I was able to successfully validate the field. However, I received a strange problem. When the fields are validated as either valid or invalid, the **glyphicon-ok** icon and **glyphicon-remove** icon appeared at the side of the screen instead of in the textbox. **Furthermore**, the glyphicon-calender icon will have a hight that is **bigger** than the text box **only if** the start date field is evaluated as **invalid** and an **error message** is displayed. Why is that so?

***Edit***: I've successfully solved  the problem where "the glyphicon-calender icon will have a height that is **bigger** than the text box **only if** the start date field is evaluated as **invalid** and an **error message** is displayed." I am still currently trying to solve why the *glyphicon-ok** icon and **glyphicon-remove** icon appeared at the side of the screen instead of in the textbox

[image: Error screenshot]

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/gud7xjy0/23/

```
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="moneyInput">money</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" id="moneyInput" name="moneyInput" class="form-control font-bold"
               maxlength="100" placeholder="money" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="startDateInput">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="input-group date" id="startDateInput" style="max-width: 280px" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDateInput">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon-ok').remove();
                $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon-remove').remove();
                $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#dataForm').validate({
        rules: {
            startDateInput: {
                required: true
            },
            moneyInput: {
                required: false
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The size problem has absolutely nothing to do with the Glyphicon.  It's being caused by how/where you're inserting the error message.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/gud7xjy0/24/

Comment: As far as placing the Glyphicons properly, I don't know how you put it "inside" of the input element.  But you have to inspect your DOM and adjust the jQuery DOM traversal in order to put the icons elsewhere.